# Ubuntu crash during the update to 13.10

Tags: 13.04, package-management, crash

I just tried to update from 13.04 to 13.10. However, during the process, my internet connection was cut and I restarted the computer. The installation was not successful and my computer is very slow and many options don't work. Among them, the internet connection. I tried to restart in recovery mode. I found out that many packages were missing (many of them python packages). However, since my internet access doesn't work (I can't connect with ubuntu), I can't download them. How can I fix these packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't have any possibility to download the packages, you could reinstall them from your Setup CD/Stick. (I don't know how but I know it's possible)

Since some of your software may be upgraded to 13.10 and some is still 13.04, this could result in some kind of "hybride system". To avoid such problems, the best way to do this is to setup your PC from scratch. (Get a Ubuntu Saucy ISO and install it over the existing system)

Whatever you do, **create a backup** of your personal files **before doing anything else!**

Comment: this is actually more complicated. I downloaded lili on a usb key, but when connecting my key to my ubuntu, it is not detected... I must have broken a package there. Is it possible to download packages on a usb drive and installing them? (like apt-get upgrade, but using a usb drive?)

Comment: Is your computer actually capable of USB booting?

Comment: yes it is capable of. But I don't think lili enables to repair broken packages this way